# How to allow a .NET Core web app access to network drives?

Tags: c#, .net-core, iis

I am implementing a .NET Core (3.1) web api that reads files from a network drive, does string manipulations in them, and writes them out in a different folder (within the same network drive).

The goal is to trigger that process through an HTTP request.

To achieve that, I created my web api project, deployed to IIS 10 (win10), and the web application runs perfectly.

However, I always run into permissions issues when trying to access the network drive:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\\my\network\drive' is denied.
   at System.IO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(String fullPath, Byte[] securityDescriptor)
   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
   ...
```

I have tried using all different identities under Application Pool -> Advances Settings -> Identity, and nothing worked.

What I hear from my company's infrastructure team, authorization to this network drive are granted at the user level, so it would not be possible to just give permissions to my web server's machine account to access the drive (apologies if I am not using proper terminology here - not a networking guy).

I have a .NET Core web app that receives an HTTP request, and when it does, it is supposed to read and write files that exist in a network drive. However, System.UnauthorizedAccessException is thrown, preventing my application from accessing the network drive and its contents.

I think I cannot allow access to my network drive to group IIS_IUSRS (the group for application pool users), because it is a local group in the machine that hosts my application. That being the case, maybe what I need is to configure that application pool to run as a specific domain user that has read/write permissions in my network drive. Is this even possible? If so, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: If you open File Explorer and paste \\my\network\drive, do you see the contents?

Comment: What user is your app pool running under? _Be specific._

Comment: @Delphi.Boy more importantly: if the *user account that the web-server is running as* does that: does *it* see the contents?

Comment: @Delphi.Boy, yes, I can access the drive just fine.

Comment: @mjwills, when I right-click my app pool and go to Advanced Settings, the Identity is set to LocalSystem. Note that I am on IIS 10.

Comment: @MarcGravell good question. Any pointers on how I can verify that? Sorry, not a network guy.

Comment: Go to Services and make sure WWW Service is being run under your own user account (which has access to the network folder).

Answer (score 2):

This is because your drive has set access permissions and the application cannot access it.

Right click on your drive directory, then click "Properties":

[image]

Click "Edit":

[image]

I recommend giving all "Group or user names" full control permissions:

[image]

Comment: The thing is, as far as I'm concerned, application pools as run by users in group IIS_IUSRS, and this group is local to the machine hosting the application. It is not a domain group that I can set permissions for in my network drive.

Comment: @Lewis So change the app pool to run under a domain identity.

Comment: @mjwills I think that is exactly what I have to do. But I cant find anything that helps me do that in IIS 10. Any thoughts?

Comment: This answer is not a good idea for a network folder!

Comment: You can try to grant permissions to NETWORK SERVICE user. This has a similar question, you can refer to this link: https://forums.asp.net/t/1013434.aspx?System+UnauthorizedAccessException+Access+to+the+path+D+thumbs+5B62060C102F6363635A+jpg+is+denied+

Comment: ***This is extremely dangerous!*** Giving _anyone_ other than SYSTEM or Global Admins group "Full Control" over a folder is generally a very bad idea. Especially for an application that just needs write access to some files in one folder a network drive. Just give one account "Modify" rights to the folder and then have the application run under that user context in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use an account that has access to the path to run the app pool. And ensure "Load User Profile" is set to True!